# mongo c driver update nested array

Tags: c, arrays, mongodb, gcc, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to use the mongo c driver to update a nested array inside of a single document.  Here is an example test document:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c"), 
  "folder1" : [
    {
      "folder_id" : "5624200d4bacd3940b8b2d62", 
      "some" : "data"
    }, 
    {
      "folder_id" : "562940084bacf60575d3b17e", 
      "some" : "data"
    }
  ], 
  "folder2" : [
    {
      "folder_id" : "5627e20d4bacefccf4864e4e", 
      "some" : "data"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to iterate through both `"folder1"` and `"folder2"` looking for any `"folder_id"` that match a specific string (EX: `5624200d4bacd3940b8b2d62`).  Then I wish to remove that entire element from the array.  So after removal my document should look like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c"), 
  "folder1" : [
    {
      "folder_id" : "562940084bacf60575d3b17e", 
      "some" : "data"
    }
  ], 
  "folder2" : [
    {
      "folder_id" : "5627e20d4bacefccf4864e4e", 
      "some" : "data"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to modify a single element in the document, example below.  But I have not found any good examples of iterating through nested array elements.

```
update = BCON_NEW ("$set", "{","some_cool_key", BCON_UTF8 ("some cool data for key"),"}");
mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_NONE, query, update, NULL, &error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to give credit to John Moore @ ObjectRocket for helping me with this.  He provided a simple one-line BCON that does exactly what I need:

```
update = BCON_NEW ("$pull", "{", "folder1", "{", "folder_id", BCON_UTF8 ("5624200d4bacd3940b8b2d62"), "}", "}");
```

Comment: The only "down side" to this is it only does folder1.  To address this I just execute the command twice (once for folder1 and a second time for folder2)